# Macro - Query - Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process

Tags: excel, ms-access, macros, vba

I'm trying to execute a query from `excel macro`. The query was working  just fine till yesterday. When I ran it today, it threw an error message "

> The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you
>   and other user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.

But I'm sure, no one else is trying to change anything. Any other possibilities for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Do a Compact and Repair to clean things up.  Also, this problem occurs if fields with a bit data type in the SQL Server-based database have been left blank.  Microsoft Access interprets blank fields as fields that contain Null values, and the Jet database engine does not release them.  As a result, the records remain locked and are not available for deletion.  Finally, make sure you are not using any reserved words for any objects (Tables, Field Names, etc.).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286335